# if edittext has an image how to get all from edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext

In my app i show some html code in edit text using `fromhtml()` method. Now I need to get all from edit text. How to do that?
Now i am using `gettext()` method. But it will get only the text not an image. Please help me. 
Thanks advance.

Comment: can u show some code plz?

Comment: ok say me y u wanna go for edittext only? y not imageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool try this :
if u r using some html style in text this code will work :

```
String htmlString=Html.toHtml(edittext.getText());
```